# Connection refused when binding a service to specific interface using bridge networks in docker

Tags: docker, networking

Here my docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  service1:
    image: alpine/socat
    command: TCP-LISTEN:9999,bind=127.16.1.10 SYSTEM:"echo lol"

    networks:
      network1:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.1.10

  service2:
    image: alpine/socat
    entrypoint: ''
    command: sh -c 'sleep 2 && ping -c 1 172.16.1.10 && socat - TCP4:172.16.1.10:9999'
    depends_on: 
      - service1

    networks:
      - network1


networks:
    network1:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: 172.16.1.0/24
```

Both services are sharing the `network1` network, `service1` get the ip 172.16.1.10 and socat is binding to this ip.

If I run:

```
$ docker-compose run service2
Creating network "docker_network1" with driver "bridge"
Creating docker_service1_1 ... done
PING 172.16.1.10 (172.16.1.10): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.16.1.10: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.197 ms

--- 172.16.1.10 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.197/0.197/0.197 ms
2020/06/07 16:06:15 socat[1] E connect(5, AF=2 172.16.1.10:9999, 16): Connection refused
```

`Socat` does not accept the connection.

If I change binding to 0.0.0.0, it works, but I don't want to bind to all interfaces, I'm using networks for this purpose, this is pointless if I can't bind my services on specific interfaces.

Is it not possible in Docker or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on docker 19.03.7 on Linux. The issue seems to be on docker for mac.

Comment: Why do you want this detailed control over the network setup?  If I was running this I'd delete all of the manual `networks:` setup and use the Compose-provided `default` network, bind the server to 0.0.0.0 (with visibility limited by the Docker network), and use the service name `server1` as the target host from the client.